# Are there any disadvantages to using a microSD card with an adapter as opposed to a SD card?

Tags: memory-card, sdcard, microsd

... for the purpose of being able to show the pictures just taken on a tablet, which takes microSD cards?

Are there any disadvantages to this approach one should be aware of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main disadvantages are:

- Slower speeds available in the microSD format as compared to full size SD
- Additional cost of the microSD format
- The addition of another piece that can fail, be lost, etc.
- The microSD cards are so small that some people are afraid of losing them or breaking them easily

In today's market, the first two points are typically less of an issue than in the past. If you have a compelling reason to use microSD, then I would say go for it.

Comment: microSD are fiddly to handle too - although that could just be my fat fingers!

Comment: Comparing Sandisk's range of microSD and SD cards (http://www.sandisk.com/products/memory-cards/microsd/ http://www.sandisk.com/products/memory-cards/sd/) their speeds seem to be up to par. Is anything lost when "going through the" microSD/SD adapter? Although I agree on the size issue (boy, do they make these things smaller and smaller every year) the idea to change the card between the camera and the tablet seems attractive to me.

Comment: @ldigas An adapter from microSD to SD is merely mechanical, it doesn't have any electronic logic itself so there is nothing lost in regard to speed. But it *is* another piece that can fail and there *is* an additional row of electrical contacts. I am using microSD with adapters but I always have a spare adapter with me and I needed to replace it more than once.

Comment: I'd be most concerned about data corruption. SD cards are already finicky; now your camera has to pass data through TWO sets of contacts which see regular exposure to the elements. However small the chance may be in the first place, you're doubling the chances of something going wrong while you're out shooting.

Comment: Yes, the additional mechanoelectrical contacts can be a problem, especially with cheap adapters. But it is less a corruption problem, more a "works/doesn't work" problem. Still annoying, but you will notice it quickly when the camera signals a card error. (Plus: [tiny chance * 2 = still tiny](https://xkcd.com/1252/)).

Answer (score 1):

Adapters can be produced very cheap, and they are.  That gives the cheap ones larger mechanical (and possibly electrical) tolerances than typical SD cards.  Anecdotically, I have a 5-pack of cheap adapters and some don't work in some readers while working in other readers/devices.

So it's likely advisable to use a brand-name adapter from a company that has the reputation and factory facilities for proper SD cards.