# Does the brand of the micro SD adapter matter?

Tags: memory-card, sdcard, microsd

For some reason (I'm unaware of what, but I'd love it if you can include this in your answer as a bonus), SD cards are considerably more expensive in my area than micro SD cards. According to [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19726/will-using-a-micro-sd-adapter-instead-of-a-normal-sd-card-affect-the-quality-o), the major difference between the two is write speed (quality not being an issue) so I'm considering getting a handful of micro SDs for my upcoming trip.

My question is: If I get a branded micro SD (like say, Fujitsu or Samsung) then use a generic non-brand micro->SD adapter with it, will it make a difference as opposed to if I were to use a branded adapter? Will I be risking the photos somehow getting corrupted (or some other risk I'm unaware of)?

If it matters, I'll be using a Samsung NX300.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have found that adapters are more fragile than full size SD cards (and SD cards are also not immune to mechanical damage). | 
Lack of card size marking can be an issue if used other than temporarily. | Adapters may lose cards if  not stored carefully enough. A small wrap of cellulose tape prevents this without making the card too large to fit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A micro SD to SD card adapter is a passive device, i.e. it does nothing but provide a set of contact points bridging those on the micro SD card and those on the SD slot. That being the case, it should pretty much either work or not work, but won't impact performance... unless you find one of such low quality that the contacts fail to accomplish their simple task.

As for disadvantages of the micro SD format itself, see [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47740/are-there-any-disadvantages-to-using-a-microsd-card-with-an-adapter-as-opposed-t).

Comment: @Arkuen - Sorry that I have absolutely no clue regarding the "bonus" economic aspect of your question. :P

Comment: Just a guess, but with all the smartphones and tablets using micro SD cards, they're probably just selling more of them with more competition on price.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've found out by now but if not here it goes. Some Brands are finicky when you're mixing sd adapters and microsd cards. I have a unirex microsd card that will only work correctly with its own adapter where as using a generic one only gets me read only, regardless of the lock mechanism on them. I'm guessing higher quality brands are impervious to this but you never know. Test before you use or you may have problems later on.