# Does a micro SD–to–SD card adapter affect the write speed of micro SD cards?

Tags: canon-550d, memory-card, sdcard, adapter, microsd

I am using a micro SD card, with an SD card adapter, in my Canon EOS 550D. I do this so that I can insert the card into my phone to view my photos and videos.

While taking videos with my Canon, video recording stops automatically, due to the slow speed of my micro SD card.

If I get fast micro SD card and use the same adapter will the problem be solved? My logic is, if the adapter affects the speed, then even if I use the fastest micro SD card it won't work well.

Comment: Please note that video questions are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Video Production](http://video.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @PhilipKendall the question boils down to whether an sd adapter influences card speed. I think that is relevant for here. The q could use some reformulation, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the brand of the micro SD adapter matter?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60530/does-the-brand-of-the-micro-sd-adapter-matter) Note that the title of the linked question is slightly misleading: the linked question asks if using a non-branded microSD-to-SD Card adapter will impact performance.

Answer (score 7):

Micro SD to SD adaptors are just passive wiring adaptors. So they should not have any impact on speed.

Comment: It'd be worth adding a teensy analysis showing that the round-trip lag is a small fraction of the clock speed :-) .   I have seen failures when a 9U computer board is mounted on a 30-cm extender card and the distance from the backplane bus causes sync failures.  It's pretty obvious that the 5mm or so distance increase caused with the SD adapter card won't foul up the data sync .

Answer (score -2):

personally I'd avoid doing that for the following reasons
1) theres a chance the adapter could deform and thus become stuck inside the camera - potentially an expensive effort to remove and/or fix

2) another potential failure mode. We all know memory cards can misbehave at the worse times (usually important times). Having a card going into an adapter which goes into a camera introduces another step where something could go wrong and you MAY lose photos. I'd stick with a dedicated card personally - but I am the paranoid type

Comment: Do you have any source for the likelihood of an SD to micro SD adaptor deforming? Anecdotally, the few adaptors I have don't seem any less rigid than a normal SD card.

Comment: I've been using SD to micro adapters for years in cameras and all sorts of gadgets.  There's absolutely no evidence of any kind of degradation of the carrier.

Comment: The reply stated that there is a 'chance' of this occurring and yes I have had a colleague who got an adapter stuck in his DSLR camera which fortunately after some careful work we managed to retrieve. It does happen so I'm just issuing a caution nothing else

Comment: Even then, that wasn't the question.